# I can close an AudioInputStream after load the Clip object?

Tags: java, javasound

In my code, I'm loading the sound and closing or not closing the AudioInputStream, the sound is played. Is it best to close or is it a problem?

```
        try {
        as = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("som/trippygaia1.mid"));
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(as);

        as.close(); // ?

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (clip != null) {
        clip.start();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I just checked this in a short test program. The `AudioInputStream` *does not* need to stay open in order for the `Clip` to be able to play back its audio. Incidentally, this also means that the `AudioInputStream` (but not the `Clip`) can be loaded using a try-with-resources.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for [Clip](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html) open:

Says:

> Opens the clip, meaning that it should acquire any required system resources and become operational... Note that some lines, once closed, cannot be reopened. Attempts to reopen such a line will always result in a `LineUnavailableException`.

`Clip` is a line, so its referring to the clip object and not the stream object.

That said, its probably poor practice to close a stream you just opened in a clip. To properly close the stream, make sure to call the clip's close method, which states:

> Closes the line, **indicating that any system resources in use by the line can be released.**.

Comment: For any Clip that I opened, I need a new AudioInputStream?

Comment: I can't see anything in the documentation specific to that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall if the AudioInputStream itself *needs* to be closed when you are done loading the audio data to the Clip. I think the AudioInputStream puts some sort of lock on the resource file that you might want to release. The examples I have seen of Java Clip usage don't include a command to close the AudioInputStream. But it shouldn't hurt to close it, once the Clip has been built, afaik.

I look forward to a correction if this turns out to be misinformed.